# Resampling by Date, how to write a condition on the sum column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to resample data by datetime, frequency is three day, and sum the weight column. But if the sum of weight is greater than 1000, then stop sum. How can i write this sum condition, i have already write a code to resample data without any condition.

```
data1 = data.groupby('buyer_id').resample('3D',on='wh_inbound_sg_time').actual_weight.sum()
```

Table format:

```
order_sn|buyer_name buyer_id|ordersn|whs_code|consignment_no|actual_weight|time
```

Result:

```
buyer_id  time
19051     2021-08-04              32
          2021-08-07              71
          2021-08-10               0
          2021-08-13               0
          2021-08-16               0
          2021-08-19              18
          2021-08-22               0
          2021-08-25             174
          2021-08-28               0
          2021-08-31             266
          2021-09-03               0
          2021-09-06               0
          2021-09-09             372
          2021-09-12               0
          2021-09-15             192
          2021-09-18             436
          2021-09-21             456
64155     2021-09-06            1964
          2021-09-09               0
          2021-09-12               0
          2021-09-15               0
          2021-09-18             940
```

Comment: please provide a minimal example, including the input

Comment: Why don't you just cap to 1000 after the summing?